# Difference between Graphics and Graphics2D?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

What is difference between **Graphics** and **Graphics2D**?
Whether  Graphics2D is extend of Graphics?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawRect(25, 25, 20, 20); //use Graphics to paint rectangle
    Graphics2D g2 =(Graphics2D)g;
    g2.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 20); // use Graphics2D to paint rectangle
}
```

Comment: It is practically the Graphics class with methods of AffineTransform class.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Graphics itself is an `abstract class`, therefore you cant create its instance. It only defines some interface and some functionality, so it can be extended by other class.

So even this `Graphics g`, which is used as parameter in `paintComponent`, is not only `Graphics`. The standard java library has only two extended class : `DebugGraphics, Graphics2D`, so the `Graphics g` you are using is `Graphics2D` instance stored in `Graphics g`.

If it is not, the line `Graphics2D g2 =(Graphics2D)g;` would end with an error.